# this.resource displaying blank page, but returning the model (using console.log() )

Tags: ember.js

i'm currently building an ember app using Yeoman Ember Generator.

this is my template folder structure looks like:

```
template
   |---requisitions
          |---draft.hbs
          |---pending.hbs
          |---waiting.hbs
    requisitions.hbs
    app.hbs
    application.hbs
```

this is my router.js

```
Metabuyer.Router.map(function () {
    this.route('app');
    this.resource('requisitions', function(){
        this.resource('draft');
        this.resource('pending');
        this.resource('waiting');
    });
});
```

in my DS.Store , i have Requisition model which working just fine.

```
Metabuyer.RequisitionsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {
        return this.store.findAll('requisition');
    }
});
```

Draft, pending and waiting route share the same requisition model but filter it based on their needs, like below

```
Metabuyer.DraftRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function(params){
    var filterResult = this.store.filter('requisition', function(requisition){
        return requisition.get('state') === 'draft';
    });
    console.log(test);

    return filterResult;
    });
}
```

});

My problem is.
When i use `this.resource('draft')` in my router nothing is being rendered in my page (blank page), but in my console, the filtered objects are being returned.

if i used `this.route('draft')` the page is rendered, but the content of the page are not filtered, or should i say, my `Metabuyer.DraftRoute` is not being called.

Thank you so much for your help,  :'(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/

> Routes nested under a resource take the name of the resource plus their name as their route name.

An index route is also needed on parent routes.

So navigating to `/requistions` loads up the `RequesitionsRoute` and `RequisitionsIndexRoute` you need to set the model on `RequisitionsIndexRoute` and use `RequisitionsIndexController`etc. You will need to rename `requisitions.hbs` to `index.hbs` and move it to the requisitions directory.

You also need to prefix your draft route object name with the parent so `DraftRoute` becomes `RequisitionsDraftRoute` and the same for controllers, views etc.

Comment: Thanks alot!! :) 
I was so stress the whole day looking at my code. should have read the guides carefully.